# "SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND" property is not working with JettyConnectorProvider for Jersey 2.x(2.25.1)

Tags: jersey-2.0, patch, http-proxy

For Patch method support, we have to add a property HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND which is eligible for Http URL Connector but this does not have support for Proxy method.

For Proxy support we have to go for JettyConnectorProvider or ApacheConnectorProvider, but these connector loses property SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, and with this Patch support.

Is there any workaround or fix?